# problem finding 16 point DFT using two 8 point FFT (Divide and combine algorithm) MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fft, dft

Write MATLAB code that determines and plot the N-point Discrete Fourier Transform of x[n] defined by the following equations:

x[n]=0.5*pi*n      n=0:16

Compute and plot 16-point DFT using two 8-point FFTs and combining techniques?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no attempt at homework is made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will only give insight how to work on above problem but I won't give you the matlab code it can solved using two methods.
Method_1:- using DIT FFT algorithm hear inputs given in bit reversal order and output is multiplied with twiddle factor$w_n^k,where  k=0,1,2..,7$
[image: example of obtaining 8 point DFT using 4 point DIT FFT algorithm.]

So you use the same for your problem.
Method_2:- using DIF FFT algorithm hear the inputs are given in normal order at the output the butterfly's used are 2X2 & output is taken in bit reversal order like below
[image: 2X2 butterfly structure used in DIF FFT algorithm]